# The external ID of wsm message sender

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I am using OMNET 5.0, SUMO-0.25.0 and VEINS-4.4. When a vehicle receive a message; `onData()` is called.  I can get external ID of the current vehicle  using `mobility->getExternalId()`; but how I know the the external ID of **wsm message sender**

The code for initialize():

```
void TraCIDemo11p::initialize(int stage) {
    BaseWaveApplLayer::initialize(stage);
    if (stage == 0) {
        mobility = TraCIMobilityAccess().get(getParentModule());
        traci = mobility->getCommandInterface();
        traciVehicle = mobility->getVehicleCommandInterface();
        annotations = AnnotationManagerAccess().getIfExists();
        ASSERT(annotations);
        getExternalID =  mobility->getExternalId();
        sentMessage = false;
        lastDroveAt = simTime();

        findHost()->subscribe(parkingStateChangedSignal, this);
        isParking = false;
        sendWhileParking = par("sendWhileParking").boolValue();
    }
}
```

The code for onData():

```
void TraCIDemo11p::onData(WaveShortMessage* wsm) {
    std::cout << " I am "<< getExternalID  <<"and I received a message from ???? "<<endl;
    findHost()->getDisplayString().updateWith("r=16,green");
    annotations->scheduleErase(1, annotations->drawLine(wsm->getSenderPos(), mobility->getPositionAt(simTime()), "blue"));

    if (mobility->getRoadId()[0] != ':') 
          traciVehicle->changeRoute(wsm->getWsmData(), 9999);
    if (!sentMessage) 
          sendMessage(wsm->getWsmData());

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vehicle can be represented by two identifiers, either that one gotten from **SUMO** (i.e., calling *getExternalId()*) or that one of **veins** (*myId* normally), the one used in *WaveShortMessage* after calling *getSenderAddress()* is *myId* so I suggest that you focus on that last one.

Take a look on these two files to get a better idea on the used identifier and the existing methods: "BaseWaveApplLayer.h/.cc" & "WaveShortMessage_m.h/.cc"

I hope this helps.